# docker image creation failed | system-release-2-16.amzn2.x86_64", is not currently supported

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I was trying to run below docker file but getting error

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN yum install -y initscripts bash g++ gcc icu git
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
# Install as Root
RUN yum install -y nodejs https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --progress=false --production
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Error

### Inspecting system...

- uname -m
  system-release-2-16.amzn2.x86_64
  exec redhat-release
  Release package: system-release-2-16.amzn2.x86_64

### Confirming "el2-x86_64" is supported...

- curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_12.x/el/2/x86_64/nodesource-release-el2-1.noarch.rpm'

### Your distribution, identified as "system-release-2-16.amzn2.x86_64", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support

The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Can you build your image `FROM node:12` instead of installing it by hand?  Node 12 is very very old, and [end-of-lifed](https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule) at this point; can you use a newer version of Node?